# unattend.xml account created but no admin rights

Tags: windows, wds, unattended

I have my unattend.xml right here:

https://pastebin.com/FBiy3RTK

It creates the admin account witj the password that is stated but for some reason it doesnt putt it in the group administr a tors altough above the user admin it says group administrators.

Does somebody know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The Best Solution is, to use the BuildIn Administrator Account. The trick is to enable them on setup. But on my example I also created a 2. admin account.

```
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <RunSynchronous>
                <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <Path>net user administrator /active:yes</Path>
                    <Description>Activate Buildin Administrator</Description>
                </RunSynchronousCommand>
            </RunSynchronous>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>XXXX</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>XXXX</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description>local Admin Account</Description>
                        <DisplayName>Maintainer</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Name>Maintainer</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```